# Class with many inheriting class with one generic list

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a class

```
public class BaseHeaderFooterItem
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string EnTitle { get; set; }
  public HyperLink Link { get; set; }
  public int Level { get; set; }
  public HyperLink MobileLink { get; set; }
}
```

Many other class inherit from him
I want to have on generic list in the class BaseHeaderFooterItem
that will be able to hold a list from any type of the inherited classes.
something like this:

```
public class BaseHeaderFooterItem
    {
      public string Title { get; set; }
      public string EnTitle { get; set; }
      public HyperLink Link { get; set; }
      public int Level { get; set; }
      public HyperLink MobileLink { get; set; }
      public List<T> Descendants { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: `List<BaseHeaderFooterItem>` will do.

Comment: @haim770  it wont.  for example if I have an inherited class from BaseHeaderFooterItem, named TvGuid and want the Descendants  to hold a class of TvGuid, i wont work

Comment: @AdamB it should. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: @haim770 it wont. for example if I have an inherited class from BaseHeaderFooterItem, named TvGuid and want the Descendants to hold a class of TvGuid, i wont wor

Comment: If you have a derived class exactly what type should the list hold for it.  Any `BaseHeaderFooterItem` or only items of that derived class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to keep a properties to hold a child collection of the base type.

```
public class BaseHeaderFooterItem
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string EnTitle { get; set; }
  public HyperLink Link { get; set; }
  public int Level { get; set; }
  public HyperLink MobileLink { get; set; }

  // here you can add instances of BaseHeaderFooterItem and any inherits type
  public List<BaseHeaderFooterItem> Descendants { get; set; } 
}
```

And you could add any tpe that inherits from `BaseHeaderFooterItem`, for sample:

```
var list = new List<BaseHeaderFooterItem>();

list.Add(new BaseHeaderFooterItem() {
        Title = "Test"
        Descendants = new List<BaseHeaderFooterItem>()
                                 {
                                    new ChildHeaderFooterItem() { /* properties */}
                                 }
    });
```

Or if you need a specif type for each `BaseHeaderFooterItem`, than try to specif the generic on the declaration.

```
public class BaseHeaderFooterItem<T>
             where T : BaseHeaderFooterItem<T>
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string EnTitle { get; set; }
  public HyperLink Link { get; set; }
  public int Level { get; set; }
  public HyperLink MobileLink { get; set; }

  // only T types
  public List<T> Descendants { get; set; }
}

var list = new List<BaseHeaderFooterItem<ChildType>>();

list.Add(new BaseHeaderFooterItem() {
        Title = "Test"
        Descendants = new List<ChildType>()
                                 {
                                    new ChildHeaderFooterItem() { /* properties */}
                                 }
    });
```

Comment: Maybe with a `where T : BaseHeaderFooterItem<T>` constraint?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this pattern

```
public interface IBaseHeaderFooterItem
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    string EnTitle { get; set; }
    public HyperLink Link { get; set; }
    int Level { get; set; }
    HyperLink MobileLink { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseHeaderFooterItem<T> : IBaseHeaderFooterItem 
                                                where T : IBaseHeaderFooterItem
{
    public List<T> Descendants { get; set; }

     public abstract string Title { get; set; }
     public abstract string EnTitle { get; set; }
     public abstract HyperLink Link { get; set; }
     public abstract int Level { get; set; }
     public abstract HyperLink MobileLink { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can inherit from `BaseHeaderFooterItem<T>` and T is constraint to be a class implementing `IBaseHeaderFooterItem` and having all those properties.